# Image in navigation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is what I am trying to recreate. A basic nav.
[image]

As you can see here, there is an image next to the "ABOUT US" text, that is what I am having trouble with. How exactly can I make the img appear before the "ABOUT US" text? It always appears above it. Thanks in advance!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}



body {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    padding: 2em 4em;
    background-color: #121b21;
}

.nav-area {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-area li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    color: #c4cbcf;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <img src="header_logo.png" alt="Logo header">
            <ul class="nav-area">
                <li>ABOUT US</li>
                <li>CONSULTING</li>
                <li>SKYLIGHT</li>
                <li>CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: try giving the image a `width: 40px` or whatever the width of your image is, and add `width: calc(100% - 40px)` to your nav-area class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a `display:flex;` property to `nav` and it will work :) Then you can adjust other CSS accordingly.

You may also set `display:flex;` on `.nav-area`, then you don't need `inline-block` on `.nav-area li's`.

```
.nav-area {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

**CODEPEN WORKING DEMO:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/WNGYJjq

```css
   
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    width:25px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left:1.5em;
}



body {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    padding: 2em 4em;
    background-color: #121b21;
}

nav{
 display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.nav-area {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-area li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    color: #c4cbcf;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Logo header">
            <ul class="nav-area">
                <li>ABOUT US</li>
                <li>CONSULTING</li>
                <li>SKYLIGHT</li>
                <li>CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this.

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If you want logo goes to left and nav-menu goes to right, try like this.

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the float attribute to the `img` CSS declaration to obtain the desired lay-out.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
```